# Implementing a simple 64 bit Windows function in assembly

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, x86-64, masm

Because of [this bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/350355/the-compiler-optimized-a-single-very-fast-instruct.html) in VC++ compiler I’m porting parts of my code from C++ to assembly. VC++ doesn’t support inline assembly for 64 bit targets, so I’m forced to just create an assembly file.

Why does the following **empty** function crashes in runtime saying “Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000” ?

C++ portion:

```
extern "C"
{
    void asm_proc( const void* p1, const void* p2, void* p3 );
}

int main()
{
    asm_proc( nullptr, nullptr, nullptr );
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly portion:

```
PUBLIC asm_proc

; Save the non-volatile XMM registers to the stack starting from specified offset. This uses 160 = A0h bytes of the stack.
; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/register-usage?view=vs-2017#register-volatility-and-preservation
SAVE_XMM_REGS macro offset
    movaps [ rsp + offset ], xmm6
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 10h ], xmm7
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 20h ], xmm8
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 30h ], xmm9
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 40h ], xmm10
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 50h ], xmm11
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 60h ], xmm12
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 70h ], xmm13
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 80h ], xmm14
    movaps [ rsp + offset + 90h ], xmm15
endm

; Restore XMM registers from the stack.
LOAD_XMM_REGS macro offset
    movaps xmm15, [ rsp + offset + 90h ]
    movaps xmm14, [ rsp + offset + 80h ]
    movaps xmm13, [ rsp + offset + 70h ]
    movaps xmm12, [ rsp + offset + 60h ]
    movaps xmm11, [ rsp + offset + 50h ]
    movaps xmm10, [ rsp + offset + 40h ]
    movaps xmm8,  [ rsp + offset + 20h ]
    movaps xmm7,  [ rsp + offset + 10h ]
    movaps xmm6,  [ rsp + offset ]
endm

.CODE

align(16)
asm_proc PROC FRAME
; const void* p1: rcx
; const void* p2: rdx
; void *p3: r8

    ; Some boilerplate copy-pasted from this repository: https://github.com/lallousx86/AsmInVs/tree/master/x64asm

    ; Prologue
    sub rsp, 030h ; allocate stack space
    .allocstack 030h ; encode that change
    push rbp ; save old frame pointer
    .pushreg rbp ; encode stack operation
    mov rbp, rsp ; set new frame pointer
    .setframe rbp, 0 ; encode frame pointer
    .endprolog

    ; Need stack space for XMM6-15 registers, they're non-volatile
    sub rsp, 0C0h

    ; Save non-volatile registers we use.
    ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/register-usage?view=vs-2017#register-volatility-and-preservation
    mov QWORD ptr [ rsp ], r12
    mov QWORD ptr [ rsp + 8 ], r13
    mov QWORD ptr [ rsp + 10h ], r14
    mov QWORD ptr [ rsp + 18h ], r15
    SAVE_XMM_REGS 20h

    ; Actual code goes here, stripped out.

    ; Restore non-volatile registers
    LOAD_XMM_REGS 20h
    mov r15, QWORD ptr [ rsp + 18h ]
    mov r14, QWORD ptr [ rsp + 10h ]
    mov r13, QWORD ptr [ rsp + 8 ]
    mov r12, QWORD ptr [ rsp ]

    add rsp, ( 0C0h + 030h )
    pop rbp
    ret

asm_proc ENDP

END
```

P.S. My function doesn’t call any other functions, it’s a leaf one. The actual code I’ve stripped out does use r12-15 and xmm6-15 so I required to preserve them, [see the ABI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/register-usage?view=vs-2017#register-volatility-and-preservation.).

Comment: You free the stack using `add rsp, ( 0C0h + 030h )` and then attempt to do `pop rbp`. However you pushed `rbp` between those two chunks so you pop the wrong value. It's unclear what you need the `030h` for anyway.

Comment: @Jester Thanks a lot, fixed by doing add rsp, 0C0h / pop rbp / add rsp, 030h in the end. I wonder whether the code is now good with regards to SEH handling, and with regards to AV searching for unusual calling conventions in software.

Comment: @Jester About `30h`, windows needs up to `28h` bytes on the stack: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/178446/Indepth_Windows_x64_ABI_Stack_frames.php However, `28h` is not a multiple of 16, and I need it to be aligned to save/restore these SSE registers. That’s why I rounded up to `30h`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood that part. That is the shadow space and you only need that if you call other functions and even then, it's not at that place.